# add several values into one cell of prettyTable

Tags: python-2.7, prettytable

I have list like:

```
[1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c',], 3]
```

How can I add a line in a table to insert values of sublist

```
['a', 'b', 'c',]
```

in one cell of table. The values have to be under each other

Is there any other libs to handle this use case if prettyTable is not available?

for now  i have following code:

```
table = PrettyTable(headers)
for line in lines:
        table.add_row(line)
print table
```

but sublist is displayed as list in the cell. I haven't found any information in prettyTable documentation about adding several items into one cell

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please show the attempts you made to solve the problem.

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be hellpufull for someone:

list

```
['a', 'b', 'c',]
```

should be converted in such format

```
"\n".join(['a', 'b', 'c',]).
```

And than new string has to replace sublist so final result has to be

```
[1, 2, 'a\nb\nc', 3].
```

In such way 3-rd element of the list will be displayed as three elements one under another while using prettyTable